# Unable to delete a Rundeck Job via webAPI

Tags: rundeck

I am unable to delete a rundeck job using API. The error message is below

```
{"error":true,"apiversion":38,"errorCode":"api.error.job.delete.failed","message":"Job could not be deleted: Cannot delete Job \"Junk_Extract\" [22d05f6a-c9e4-4388-863-668b7f8db411]: it may have been modified or executed by another user"}
```

The command I have used:

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'https://localhost:4443/api/38/job/22d05f6a-c9e4-4388-8a63-668b7f8db411' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: 7kotazOO3xRr43qeZl3CQnYcKwzU6' -k
```

How can I delete a rundeck job?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the execution/schedule first, under admin rights:

1. Disable executions for that jobs using [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#disable-executions-for-a-job) endpoint.
2. Disable the schedule for that job using [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#disable-scheduling-for-a-job) endpoint.
3. Then delete it using [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#deleting-a-job-definition) endpoint.

Comment: I have tried disabling the execution and then scheduling for a job and tried deleting the job.
still the same error. :(

Answer (score 0):

The error says: it may have been modified or executed by another user.
Is the token used assigned to user with sufficient privileges for job deletion?